# Swift. Can't Connect my Button to GIDSignIn Button in my Class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to the swift. I follow the google tutorial to use Firebase Google OAuth method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

At step 9, I try to connect a custom button by `control + drag` to my property :

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
```

But Xcode doesn't select it. It shows a pop up to create a new property. Though I have two others button: UIButton and when I try to connect to them, it works.

Could help me with that? It might miss some elements of my problem, so don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag from the empty circle on the left of @IBOutlet to your button (not vice versa)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was possible to do that too!